# Loading map tiles using own javascript function

Tags: javascript, algorithm, dictionary

I have my own map tiles server where map images are saved,I want to write a javascript engine which can load required map tiles on scroll and double click(just like google map).
I am using openstreet map javascript algo to calculate exact tile path

```
function long2tile(lon,zoom) {
    return (Math.floor((lon+180)/360*Math.pow(2,zoom)));
}

function lat2tile(lat,zoom) {
    return (Math.floor((1-Math.log(Math.tan(lat*Math.PI/180) + 1/Math.cos(lat*Math.PI/180))/Math.PI)/2 *Math.pow(2,zoom)));
}
```

But i just want to know how to load tiles when user double click or scroll on map.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the openstreet map javascript api, and I don't now the architecture of your web page, but it could be possible to load dynamically whatever image in your web page, using an Image object, and changing the src property of the object:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_image.asp

You should be able to access to the Image Object in your web page using:

document.getElementById('yourImageId')